# Closed-form of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp {(-ax^2)}\log x \mathrm d x$ without using Laplace Transform?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, closed-form

I want to get the closed-form of the followng integral without using Laplace Transform but I didn't succeed with $a$ is a positive real number.

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp {(-ax^2)}\log x  \mathrm dx,$$

[Wolfram alpha](//www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(+exp(-+a+x%C2%B2)log+x)),+x%3D0+to+infty) give me nice closed-form. Then is there any way without using Laplace Transform ?

Comment: Could you maybe include your own work, i.e. your solution utilizing the Laplace Transform? I think this, one could say "lack of context" is why your interesting question already received a down-vote aswell as a close-vote.

Comment: Is there anything I could improve which prevents you right now from accepting my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may exploit Feynman's Trick in this situation.

In order to perform the actual trick we define the following integral

> $$I(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s+1}\exp(-ax^2)\mathrm dx$$

We are specifically interested in the value of $I'(-1)$ which equals your given integral. However, first of all lets evaluate the newly defined integral $I(s)$. The pretty straightforward substitution $ax^2\mapsto x$ reveals

\begin{align*}
I(s)&=\int_0^\infty x^{s+1}\exp(-ax^2)\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac xa\right)^{\frac{s+1}2}\exp(-x)\left[\frac1{2\sqrt{ax}}\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12a^{-\frac s2-1}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac s2}\exp(-x)\mathrm dx\\
\therefore~I(s)&=\frac12a^{-\frac s2-1}\Gamma\left(\frac s2+1\right)
\end{align*}

Now we can differentiate this closed-form of $I(s)$ w.r.t. $s$ and evaluate the so gained expression at $s=-1$ which yields to

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}I(s)&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\frac12a^{-\frac s2-1}\Gamma\left(\frac s2+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(-\frac12\log(a)a^{-\frac s2-1}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac s2+1\right)+\frac12a^{-\frac s2-1}\left[\frac12\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac s2+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac s2+1\right)\right]\\
&=\frac14a^{-\frac s2-1}\Gamma\left(\frac s2+1\right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac s2+1\right)-\log(a)\right]
\end{align*}

Here $\psi^{(0)}(z)$ denotes the [Digamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html). Plugging in $s=-1$ finally gives

\begin{align*}
I'(-1)&=\frac14a^{\frac12-1}\Gamma\left(-\frac 12+1\right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(-\frac 12+1\right)-\log(a)\right]\\
&=\frac1{4\sqrt a}\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\left[\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac12\right)-\log(a)\right]\\
&=-\frac14\sqrt{\frac\pi a}[\gamma+2\log 2+\log a]
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\int_0^\infty \exp(-ax^2)\log(x)\mathrm dx~=~-\frac14\sqrt{\frac\pi a}[\gamma+2\log 2+\log a]$$

I will not go into detail how to obtain the values for the Gamma Function and Digamma Function, respectively, which are afterall well-known. The crucial equality, namely

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\int_0^\infty x^{s+1}\exp(-ax^2)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial s}x^{s+1}\exp(-ax^2)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty \log(x)x^{s+1}\exp(-ax^2)\mathrm dx$$

Which is essentially Feynman's Trick, can be justified by the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), or Integration Under The Integral Sign, which allows the aforementioned procedure if certain conditions hold.